# Property or method not defined in .vue file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-loader

Everything in my app was working perfectly fine until I began to add my javascript. Now I continuously get errors in the console.

I get this error:

> ***Property or method "show" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.***

As well as this error:

> ```
> TypeError: _vm.show is not a function
>   at click App.vue?d98c:25
>   at HTMLButtonElement.invoker vue.esm.js?efeb:1906
> ```

Desired Outcome: Click on "loginBtn" alert prompts "click".

---

My code:

```
// app.vue script 
export default {
  name: 'app'
}

var show = new Vue({
  el: '#loginBtn',
  data: {
    n: 0
  },
  methods: {
    show: function(event) {
      targetId = event.currentTarget.id;
      alert('click')
    }
  }
})
```

```
<!-- the button -->
<template>
  <div>
    <button v-on:click="show($event)" id="loginBtn">Login</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a [Single-File Component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) (a `.vue` file), which is a file format for a Vue component definition used by [`vue-loader`](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/).

The script section of a `.vue` file (what's inside the `<script>` tag) should export an object specifying the definition of the Vue instance.

[From the documentation:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)

> The script must export a Vue.js component options object. Exporting an extended constructor created by Vue.extend() is also supported, but a plain object is preferred.

---

You are currently only exporting `{ name: 'app' }`, which is why Vue can't find the `show` method.

Your `<script>` section should look like this:

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    data() {
      return { n: 0 }
    },
    methods: {
      show: function(event) {
        targetId = event.currentTarget.id;
        alert('click')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Note also that the `data` property of the object exported needs to be a function returning the data properties. [See the "Why does `data` need to be a function" section of Vue's Common Beginner Gotchas page.](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/)

Comment: Yayyy! Tysm, been looking for hours, but there are so many different methods of achieving this I suppose. Also, none others that I have found explained that it should within the export, most said to create a ('new Vue')

Comment: Glad to help! And yes, `.vue` files follow a specific format which `vue-loader` uses to abstract out some boilerplate code (like needing to instantiate via `new Vue`). I edited my post to link to some documentation you'd probably find helpful.