# Vue method "logout" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I've read through several answers to this error message, but none has managed to solve my issue. I'm simply trying to call a method when I click on a button, which seems so simple I can't see how many things there are to go wrong.

How is my "logout" method not visible to the @click handler?

**NavBar.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="">CSW</a>
                <button @click="logout" class="btn float-right">Log Out</button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            logout() {
                this.$store.dispatch("auth/logout")
                .then(() => {
                    this.$router.push('/login')
                });
            }
        }
    }
<script>
```

Comment: shouldn't `logout() {` be `logout: function() {`

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz No, there is a shorthand for Object methods now: [Method definition shorthand](http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/#method-definition-shorthand).  I thought the same thing the first time I saw it though.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't getting called?  Have you put a `console.log()` or some kind of debugging statement in the `logout` to see if it is getting called?

Comment: How are you using the component? Like in the parent, how is it used?

Comment: Is the second unclosed `<script>` tag a typo when copypasting here or your code is like this?

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with what you have provided: [fiddle of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/0cfjdmqp/6/).  Please address some of the the comments requesting clarification on your question because right now we have nothing more to go on.

Comment: The issue is almost certainly the unclosed script tag. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347155/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775024/

Comment: @yuriy636 ...that was it. I spent hours looking at this. Oh my god... Thankyou